# Component joomla 2.5 with database acces

Tags: php, database, components, joomla2.5

I need any tutorial or example to create a back/frontend component which permit to add/modify content to the corresponding component table and be able to display it on frontend.

I have looked at hello world examples but none cover the database part.

If anyone can help me please ....

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

as far as I remember, there's a class with all the database functions you need.

check out the manual here: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Comment: Thank's for your answer, that i had forgotten in my controller was `:JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'tables');`